# Pass a arraylist<ImageItems> from one activity to another.Image Item contains BITMAP and STRING

Tags: javascript, java, android, arraylist, bitmap

Pass a arraylist from one activity to another.Image Item contains BITMAP and STRING
ImageItem contains BITMAP and STRING
Passed arraylist contains multiple ImageItems

Comment: What have you tried and what are you trying to implement ? Can you post what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Your ImageItems class should implement parcelable to pass it between activities.

```
public class ImageItems implements Parcelable {
    private String mYourString;
    // Your BITMAP implementation.

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        // Break down your object here for storage into the parcel.
        out.writeString(mYourString);
        // Write your BITMAP to the parcel.
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ImageItems> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<ImageItems>() {
            public ImageItems createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new ImageItems(in);
            }

            public ImageItems[] newArray(int size) {
                return new ImageItems[size];
            }     
   };

   private ImageItems(Parcel in) {
       // Rebuild your object from the parcel here.
       mYourString = in.readString();
       // Read your BITMAP from the parcel.
   }
}
```

You should now be able to add the array list of parcelable ImageItems to your intent bundle.

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Data", mArraylist);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanx for help......................!!

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's a bad idea. Your activities should be as independent from eachother as possible, in order to be able to use the flexible.

If you absolutely insist, simply use public static variables in your activity class, set them to your data and access form the other activity.

Answer (score 0):

Usually data can be passed between activities using putBundle() in the first activity and using getBundle() in the second Activity.

But in this case of custom objects, bundle implementing Parcelable or Serializable should be used.

Serializable way is easier to implement. See below.

Use below code for passing arraylist from first activity.

```
List<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();
imageItems.add(new ImageItem(//your parameters //));
imageItems.add(new ImageItem(//your parameters //));
imageItems.add(new ImageItem(//your parameters //));
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
bundle.putSerializable("data", (Serializable) imageItems);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Use below code For getting arraylist from second activity.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
List<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>(ImageItem);
imageItems = (List<ImageItem>) bundle.getSerializable("data");
```

Hope this helps. Regards.

Comment: Runtime exception :Parsable encountered IOException writing Serilizable object